# Upgrade AngularJS bindings to Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

Upgrade AngularJS controller to Angular 2.

```
export default {
    template: html,
    bindings: {
        binding1: '<',
        binding2: '<',
        binding3: '<'
    },
    controller: [SomeService, controller]
}

function controller(SomeService) {
    // code
}
```

I want to convert this to Angular 2 Component

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(){}
}
```

How to replace bindings ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
    template: html,
    selector: 'wasnt-shown-in-ngJS-example',
})
export class TestComponent {
    @Input() binding1: number;
    @Input() binding2: string;
    @Input() binding3: Foobar | null;

    constructor(private someSrv: SomeService){
    }

}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried to do the samething, But I am getting undefined for bindings value.

Comment: They will be undefined in the constructor, but will first have value in the ngOnInit() function.  If not, check the parent element and its syntax.  The kebab-case vs camelCase issue in particular.